# Javascript date comparison not incorporating year

Tags: javascript

I only want the date range to be selectable for future days and the first day should be before or the same day as the 2nd day to create a date range. 
Input is 
first date: 01/23/2020
second date: 03/19/2020
currdate: 12/11/2019

```
var curdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
if(smsBlackoutFirstDateSelect.value > smsBlackoutSecondDateSelect.value){
      alert("second date is before first date");
} else if(smsBlackoutFirstDateSelect.value <= curdate){
      alert("first date is on or before today" + " " + smsBlackoutFirstDateSelect.value + " " + 
             smsBlackoutSecondDateSelect.value + " " + curdate);
} else { 
     some success function;
}
```

Output is :
first date is on or before today 01/23/2020 03/19/2020 12/11/2019

any idea why it isn't comparing years?

Comment: You are formatting dates as strings in mm/dd/yyyy format and then doing a string comparison.  `01` comes before `03`.  Either make date objects and compare those, or format it so the most significant part of the date comes first, yyyy/mm/dd.

Comment: I think you are correct with your analysis, I went with Nasim's solution though

Comment: I covered the solution proposed by Nasim as `make date objects and compare those,...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are referring to the comparison of `curdate` with `smsBlackoutFirstDateSelect.value`,
`curdate` is not a date field.

if you want date comparison to convert it to date by

`var d1 = new Date(curdate);`
and use it
you can refer below question
[Compare two dates with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-two-dates-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're using a string to represent the date. This won't work well. Ideally, we should use javascript Date variables to handle the sorting as needed.
Try something like this and see how it compares.

Example:
3 numbers specify year, month, and day:

`var curdate = new Date(2018, 11, 24);`

I can't see how `smsBlackoutFirstDateSelect` is defined. It may also need to be casted to Dates() separately. See the other methods to create a Date() referenced below.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp